# separate column by id using foreach

Tags: php, codeigniter, foreach

I have a score table, and I will separate the column by id
my table is,

[image]

and I hope the output table will

[image]

I don't know the logic if I use foreach in CodeIgniter, thanks
and have tried this

```
foreach ($data as $row) {
        $records["list"][] = array(
            $row['ID_STUDENT'],
            $row['ID_TYPE'],
            $row['SCORE'],
        );
    }
```

Comment: First, show us your DB query? Second, you are asking for an array and showing us table can you show us expected array here

Comment: Can you paste $data in JSON form here? so we can try it at our end

Comment: I think it is all about showing the data in the desired format. Do you want to show the data in a table form?

Answer (score 0):

This will build you the array you are looking for, although I would suggest that you should write a query to retrieve your data in the format you are looking for.

```
$studentsScores = [
    ['idType'=>1, 'idStudent'=>1, 'score'=>'80'],
    ['idType'=>1, 'idStudent'=>2, 'score'=>'60'],
    ['idType'=>2, 'idStudent'=>3, 'score'=>'70'],
    ['idType'=>1, 'idStudent'=>4, 'score'=>'80'],
    ['idType'=>3, 'idStudent'=>1, 'score'=>'90'],
    ['idType'=>4, 'idStudent'=>2, 'score'=>'100'],
];

// Columns with default values 
$columns = array_fill_keys(array_unique(array_column($studentsScores, 'idType')), 0);
$res = [];
foreach($studentsScores as $record){
  if(!isset($res[$record['idStudent']])) $res[$record['idStudent']] = $columns;
  $res[$record['idStudent']][$record['idType']] = $record['score'];
}
print_r($res);
```

Hope this helps,